# MySQL: LOAD DATA INFILE + mysqlimport. Data import from external source

Tags: mysql, import

I am successfully using **LOAD DATA INFILE** for data import from local CSV file into MySQL db.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/data/order.csv' INTO TABLE order_tab
FIELDS terminated by ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@Order_Date,Order_ID,Order_Number)
SET
Order_Date = STR_TO_DATE(@Order_Date,  '%d-%b-%Y %l:%i %p MDT')
;
```

Now I need importa data from external source (server). For this purpose already exists utility: **mysqlimport**.

**Definition is**: The mysqlimport client provides a command-line interface to the LOAD DATA INFILE SQL statement. Most options to mysqlimport correspond directly to clauses of LOAD DATA INFILE syntax.

My question is: How should I rebuild my previous script for pulling data from external source, if new path is: "*\192.168.0.10:\MyDir\SubDir\order.scv*"

*note: For point-collectors (on stackoverflow) - this question is not duplicit. If you do not know answer, do not write.*

Comment: Download the file and then use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a way. I need read from external source. There is no space for download.

Comment: I'm not sure the tool supports streaming of a file.  Then find another machine to use.